# Aspherical subcomplexes of finite aspherical 2-complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Recently I have been considering the following question in low-dimensional topology, that would help with another result I have been working on, but have been assuming that the statement is likely too strong to be true. In particular it has certain similarities with the Whitehead conjecture https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_conjecture, and hence I would predict it has a similar “unlikely to be true but hard to find a counterexample” nature.

Let a group $G$ be called aspherical if there is a finite aspherical 2-complex $X$ such $\pi_1(X)=G$.

Let $H\leqslant G$ be aspherical groups, does there exist some finite aspherical 2-complex $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=G$ that has an aspherical subcomplex with fundamental group $H$?

Although I expect the above question to be open and have not been able to make any headway on it, it is very possible I have missed a trick, so any solutions, pointers in the direction of a solution or reasons to believe it is untrue would be much appreciated.

I would also like to note that as this problem is parametrised by the group $G$ we can ask for solutions for specific aspherical groups. For example is this problem made easier if we look only at 1-relator groups?

Comment: I think it is also wide-open. But read also the discussion of the Whitehead conjecture (rel. the Eilenberg-Ganea conjecture) for presentation complexes in "Morse theory and finiteness properties of groups" by Bestvina and Brady.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks for clarifying, I feared as much, and also will have a look into the paper you recommended

Comment: At risk of stating something that you know already, but the natural correspondence is between covering spaces and subgroups: if $X$ is an aspherical 2-complex with $\pi_1(X)=G$ then there is a covering space $Y$ of $X$ which is also aspherical and 2-dimensional and has $\pi_1(Y)=H$.

Comment: @IJL thanks for checking, I am aware of that correspondence but unfortunately I’m not sure this can be made particularly relevant to the above problem. In particular the difficulty stems from the realisation of aspherical $\mathcal{subcomplexes}$ with prescribed fundamental group. In fact in the answer below the counterexample to my question fits precisely into that correspondence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ be the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. It has a subgroup $H=\mathbb{Z}\rtimes 2\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. If you like, view $H$ as the image of the fundamental group of the covering of the Klein bottle by the torus. Both $G$ and $H$ are clearly aspherical.

I claim that there does not exist a finite aspherical $2$-complex $X$ with aspherical subcomplex $Y\subseteq X$ such that $\pi_1(X)=G$ and $\pi_1(Y)=H$. Such an $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the Klein bottle, and such a $Y$ to the torus, so in integral cohomology with untwisted coefficients we have
$$
H^2(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\qquad H^2(Y)\cong \mathbb{Z}.
$$
By the long exact sequence of the pair
$$
\cdots \to H^2(X)\to H^2(Y)\to H^3(X,Y)\to\cdots
$$
we see that $H^3(X,Y)$ is nonzero, contradicting that the dimension of $X$ is at most $2$.

Comment: Because any complex with fundamental group $G$ can be made into a $BG$ by attaching 3-cells and above, the map $H^2(BG) \to H^2(X)$ is injective. So your nice argument applies even to aspherical $X$ and possibly non-aspherical subcomplexes $Y$.

Comment: Thanks nice argument, I think this should completely clear the question up